# Use `geo` directive in NGINX on Heroku

Tags: nginx, heroku, geo

Duplicated from the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx/issues/61):

Please see the relevant areas of `nginx.conf.erb` below. I've tested something like this locally on my machine with nginx and `127.0.0.1` so I believe I'm using the directives properly. However when I add a CIDR group that contains my IP address and put this on my Heroku dyno I can still get through to my site.

Any ideas why this isn't being picked up properly or something I'm missing? Does this feature not work on Heroku?

```
http {
  geo $test_group {
    default 0;
    1.2.3.4/22 1; # this includes my local IP address
  }
  server {
    location / {
      if ($test_group) {
        return 418 "short AND stout";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My best guess is that theres a decent amount of IP forwarding going on behind the scenes that is screwing around with NGINX. For example if I do `curl -i -H "X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4" "https://my-cool-app.herokuapp.com"` I still see my real IP and it does not get picked up by the NGINX rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

It *is* related to IP forwarding so the `proxy` directive must be used. Simply add

```
proxy 10.0.0.0/8;
```

inside `geo` and you're good to go.

## Whaaa!? How and Why

Heroku forwards all internal requests on private IP addresses in the `10.x.x.x` range. This is probably obvious and immediately makes sense to folks more familiar with networking and/or NGINX. I was able to figure it out by returning `$remote_addr` as a header and noticed that it was *not* my public IP address. While [the docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) leave a lot to be desired for the novice, the `proxy` description clued me in that if I proxied the CIDR range for private IPs (`10.0.0.0/8`), the `X-Forwarded-For` address would be used instead.